# Need help in Timezone in Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone

I am faced with a peculiar issue with respect to Timezone in Ruby. I want to convert the following

```
Sat Sep 11 15:15:00 +0530 2010
```

to

```
Sat Sep 11 15:15:00 -0400 2010
```

As you can notice, only the time zone has been converted and no other part has changed. How to do this in Ruby.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be worth looking at the [ActiveSupport::TimeZone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html) class which Rails provides. Provided you know the time zones you are working with you can create the time in the zone you require.

For example:

```
first_time = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new("Chennai").local(2010, 9, 11, 15, 15)
second_time = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new("Eastern Time (US & Canada)").local(
  first_time.year, first_time.month, first_time.day, 
  first_time.hour, first_time.min)
```

The names of the time zones are in the documentation.